# Preventing group of users from accessing rest of clients in IdentityServer

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, identityserver4, ocelot

I am developing ASP.Net Core App with Backend For Frontend pattern using Ocelot. For now there will be a single API service but in the future I might migrate to microservices. Let's say it will be an e-commerce system where I will create different web apps for customers and for employees. I may also have Mobile app for customers.

From my research I know that should have my main API, then two API Gateways and two client (angular) apps. There also needs to be separate IdentityServer app.

So my question is - is there a way to configure the IdentityServer and gateways in such a way, that when I log in app for employees I won't be authenticated in customer app? I cannot understand if it should be possible with right configuration of scopes, claims or audiences. I saw many examples where that properties were set completely differently. I can prevent user from accesing some endpoints with the use of Roles but I think that it's not the right way to do this.

Or maybe since IdentityServer has built in SSO I should not use it and move to different authentication provider?

Answer (score 0):

You should let the authorization sub-system in ASP.NET Core decide if the user is allowed or not, typically based on the claims in the access token.

You need to understand that you handle authentication and authorization separately in ASP.NET Core as the picture from one of my training classes show:
[image]

For more details:

- [Introduction to authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/introduction?view=aspnetcore-6.0)
- [Policy-based authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-6.0)
- [Claims-based authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: Okay, then let's say i have an EmployeeId Claim on part of my users. Can I prevent authentication action based on that claim just for specific client?

Comment: You will do authentication for all incoming request, and then it is up to the authorization module to block unwanted users. There are different approaches as described in the links in my answer. The only responsibility for the authentication module is to figure who the user is.  So in the API/client, then you can add a rule that requires that the claim is present or that is has a specific value.